# How to restart glibc services without reboot?

Tags: 14.04, reboot, glibc

On the glibc issue, I realize have a serious issue with restarting ubuntu instances running on my network. It will interrupt lots of stuff for me and so I'm looking for an alternative.

[These instructions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-patch-cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack-based-buffer-overflow/) are interesting because for CentOS they have a simple command that can restart glibc services without rebooting the system.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reexec
```

So, how could I achieve the same thing with Ubuntu if I don't want to have to reboot?

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reexec` only re-executes the init process, *not* all services that use glibc.